# ffmpeg how to add mkv to formats

Tags: ffmpeg

hello after installing ffmpeg in my linux server with centos 6 after searching google i run ffmpeg -formats  so i need to add mkv i know i will need to recompile ffmpeg but i do not know how to do it
thank you

```
File formats:
 D. = Demuxing supported
 .E = Muxing supported
 --
  E 3g2             3GP2 format
  E 3gp             3GP format
 D  4xm             4X Technologies format
 D  IFF             IFF format
 D  ISS             Funcom ISS format
 D  MTV             MTV format
 DE RoQ             raw id RoQ format
 D  aac             raw ADTS AAC
 DE ac3             raw AC-3
  E adts            ADTS AAC
 D  aea             MD STUDIO audio
 DE aiff            Audio IFF
 DE alaw            PCM A-law format
 DE alsa            ALSA audio output
 DE amr             3GPP AMR file format
 D  anm             Deluxe Paint Animation
 D  apc             CRYO APC format
 D  ape             Monkey's Audio
 DE asf             ASF format
  E asf_stream      ASF format
 DE ass             SSA/ASS format
 DE au              SUN AU format
 DE avi             AVI format
  E avm2            Flash 9 (AVM2) format
 D  avs             AVS format
 D  bethsoftvid     Bethesda Softworks VID format
 D  bfi             Brute Force & Ignorance
 D  bink            Bink
 D  c93             Interplay C93
 D  caf             Apple Core Audio Format
 D  cavsvideo       raw Chinese AVS video
 D  cdg             CD Graphics Format
  E crc             CRC testing format
 DE daud            D-Cinema audio format
 DE dirac           raw Dirac
 DE dnxhd           raw DNxHD (SMPTE VC-3)
 D  dsicin          Delphine Software International CIN format
 DE dts             raw DTS
 DE dv              DV video format
 D  dv1394          DV1394 A/V grab
  E dvd             MPEG-2 PS format (DVD VOB)
 D  dxa             DXA
 D  ea              Electronic Arts Multimedia Format
 D  ea_cdata        Electronic Arts cdata
 DE eac3            raw E-AC-3
 DE f32be           PCM 32 bit floating-point big-endian format
 DE f32le           PCM 32 bit floating-point little-endian format
 DE f64be           PCM 64 bit floating-point big-endian format
 DE f64le           PCM 64 bit floating-point little-endian format
 DE ffm             FFM (FFserver live feed) format
 D  film_cpk        Sega FILM/CPK format
 DE filmstrip       Adobe Filmstrip
 DE flac            raw FLAC
 D  flic            FLI/FLC/FLX animation format
 DE flv             FLV format
  E framecrc        framecrc testing format
  E gif             GIF Animation
 D  gsm             raw GSM
 DE gxf             GXF format
 DE h261            raw H.261
 DE h263            raw H.263
 DE h264            raw H.264 video format
 D  idcin           id Cinematic format
 DE image2          image2 sequence
 DE image2pipe      piped image2 sequence
 D  ingenient       raw Ingenient MJPEG
 D  ipmovie         Interplay MVE format
  E ipod            iPod H.264 MP4 format
 D  iv8             A format generated by IndigoVision 8000 video server
 D  libdc1394       dc1394 v.2 A/V grab
 D  lmlm4           lmlm4 raw format
 DE m4v             raw MPEG-4 video format
 DE matroska        Matroska file format
 DE mjpeg           raw MJPEG video
 DE mlp             raw MLP
 D  mm              American Laser Games MM format
 DE mmf             Yamaha SMAF
  E mov             MOV format
 D  mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 QuickTime/MPEG-4/Motion JPEG 2000 format
  E mp2             MPEG audio layer 2
 DE mp3             MPEG audio layer 3
  E mp4             MP4 format
 D  mpc             Musepack
 D  mpc8            Musepack SV8
 DE mpeg            MPEG-1 System format
  E mpeg1video      raw MPEG-1 video
  E mpeg2video      raw MPEG-2 video
 DE mpegts          MPEG-2 transport stream format
 D  mpegtsraw       MPEG-2 raw transport stream format
 D  mpegvideo       raw MPEG video
  E mpjpeg          MIME multipart JPEG format
 D  msnwctcp        MSN TCP Webcam stream
 DE mulaw           PCM mu-law format
 D  mvi             Motion Pixels MVI format
 DE mxf             Material eXchange Format
  E mxf_d10         Material eXchange Format, D-10 Mapping
 D  nc              NC camera feed format
 D  nsv             Nullsoft Streaming Video
  E null            raw null video format
 DE nut             NUT format
 D  nuv             NuppelVideo format
 DE ogg             Ogg
 D  oma             Sony OpenMG audio
 DE oss             Open Sound System playback
  E psp             PSP MP4 format
 D  psxstr          Sony Playstation STR format
 D  pva             TechnoTrend PVA file and stream format
 D  qcp             QCP format
 D  r3d             REDCODE R3D format
 DE rawvideo        raw video format
  E rcv             VC-1 test bitstream
 D  rl2             RL2 format
 DE rm              RealMedia format
 D  rpl             RPL/ARMovie format
  E rtp             RTP output format
 DE rtsp            RTSP output format
 DE s16be           PCM signed 16 bit big-endian format
 DE s16le           PCM signed 16 bit little-endian format
 DE s24be           PCM signed 24 bit big-endian format
 DE s24le           PCM signed 24 bit little-endian format
 DE s32be           PCM signed 32 bit big-endian format
 DE s32le           PCM signed 32 bit little-endian format
 DE s8              PCM signed 8 bit format
 D  sdp             SDP
 D  shn             raw Shorten
 D  siff            Beam Software SIFF
 D  smk             Smacker video
 D  sol             Sierra SOL format
 DE sox             SoX native format
  E spdif           IEC958 - S/PDIF (IEC-61937)
  E svcd            MPEG-2 PS format (VOB)
 DE swf             Flash format
 D  thp             THP
 D  tiertexseq      Tiertex Limited SEQ format
 D  tmv             8088flex TMV
 DE truehd          raw TrueHD
 D  tta             True Audio
 D  txd             Renderware TeXture Dictionary
 DE u16be           PCM unsigned 16 bit big-endian format
 DE u16le           PCM unsigned 16 bit little-endian format
 DE u24be           PCM unsigned 24 bit big-endian format
 DE u24le           PCM unsigned 24 bit little-endian format
 DE u32be           PCM unsigned 32 bit big-endian format
 DE u32le           PCM unsigned 32 bit little-endian format
 DE u8              PCM unsigned 8 bit format
 D  vc1             raw VC-1
 D  vc1test         VC-1 test bitstream format
  E vcd             MPEG-1 System format (VCD)
 D  video4linux     Video4Linux device grab
 D  video4linux2    Video4Linux2 device grab
 D  vmd             Sierra VMD format
  E vob             MPEG-2 PS format (VOB)
 DE voc             Creative Voice file format
 D  vqf             Nippon Telegraph and Telephone Corporation (NTT) TwinVQ
 D  w64             Sony Wave64 format
 DE wav             WAV format
 D  wc3movie        Wing Commander III movie format
  E webm            WebM file format
 D  wsaud           Westwood Studios audio format
 D  wsvqa           Westwood Studios VQA format
 D  wv              WavPack
 D  x11grab         X11grab
 D  xa              Maxis XA File Format
 D  yop             Psygnosis YOP Format
 DE yuv4mpegpipe    YUV4MPEG pipe format
```

Comment: what version of ffmpeg is it (hint: run `ffmpeg` no parameters)?

Answer (score 3):

It's there, but it is named `matroska`, not `mkv`:

```
DE matroska        Matroska file format
```

Comment: so i can convert from mkv

Comment: i get this error when try to convert from mkv to mp4  Invalid data found when processing input

Comment: @MahmoudSaad Without the actual command and the complete console output I can't provide any suggestions. A link to the input file would be helpful too.